# Python: accessing dictionary item within JSON when JSON imported from string via loads()

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, nested

I cannot seem to get a string to load as a dictionary (via JSON) and convert embedded dictionary items in the string as the proper value from the dictionary.

Use case: I am writing an application where a text file will be used to call Python code, specifically functions. All was fine until I tried to have variables defined in the functions be dictionary items.

As an example, I previously had a text file, which line by line would call a function:

`someFunction(variable1 = 11, someListVar = [1,2,3] ...)` 
etc.

I then chaged it so that my text file would have:

`someFunction(variable1 = someDict["someKey"], someListVar = [anotherDict["anotherKey"],...] )` 
etc.

As a minimized example:

```
#this all works fine 
import json

someDict = {"One":"Good"}

x = {"someKey": someDict["One"]}

# convert into JSON string:
y = json.dumps(x)
print(y) 
>>  {"someKey": "Good"} 

print(type(y))
>><class 'str'>
```

The JSON string also behaves as expected:

```
z = json.loads(y) #this can get reloaded as a dictionary
print(z) 
>> {'someKey': 'Good'} 

print(type(z))
>> <class 'dict'>
```

But, on the other hand, if I try to START with a string, it seems like no matter how I format the string, I can't get it to bring in the dictionary value:

```
xString = '{"someKey": "someDict[\'One\']"}' #regardless of escape characters

yNew = json.loads(xString)

print(yNew)
>>{'someKey': "someDict['One']"}

print(yNew["someKey"])
>>someDict['One']
```

The easy solution, of course, is eval():

```
print(eval(yNew["someKey"])) 
#>>Good
```

But of course, this is a less than ideal solution.

FWIW I've tried different formatting of escape characters for the xString variable to no avail. I suppose I could make some sort of parser, but that seems so inelegant, especially considering this is what the JSON module is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about the way you designed your project. JSON files are *not* supposed to contain variables (variables can have different values on server/client).

You can however use templating to achieve what you are trying to do. A simple example with [jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/):

```
import json
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment()
xString = '{"someKey": "{{ someDict["One"] }}"}'
template = env.from_string(xString)
someDict = {"One":"Good"}

print(template.render(someDict=someDict))
```

Output:

```
{"someKey": "Good"}
```

Comment: That's a very nice workaround. And you're right, in most cases the server/client variable differences are important, but in this use case I wanted to make sure that the local system variables were pulled down (due to differences in how hardware is configured). I was using JSON as a convenient container, but in my application, it's probably the wrong container. I'll look into Jinja, this seems like a nice solution that has other applications for me as well. Much appreciated.